# Why does Numpy.loadtxt work when called from IDLE and gives an IOError when called from shell?

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell, numpy

I try to do the following:

## 1 VBA script calls shell using

```
RetVal = Shell(fullpythonexepath & fullscriptpath)
```

## 2 Shell get follwing command

```
fullpythonexepath & fullscriptpath
```

## 3 Python Script

```
import numpy as np

thefilepath = "input.txt"    # is in the same folder as the script
theoutputpath = "output.txt" # is in the same folder as the script

ssc=np.loadtxt(thefilepath, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0, usecols=range(2)) #error line

#some other code to fit input data

np.savetxt(theoutputpath, sscnew, header=top, fmt='%1.2f\t%1.2f')
```

When I run this the output file doesn't get printed, which means the script doesn't run properly.

Now to the funny thing: **When I run the python script from IDLE it runs fine**. When I run it from the shell using the command:

```
fullpythonexepath & fullscriptpath
```

it says :

[image]

- I tried inputting the fullpath to the input.txt and output.txt. When I do this and run it in the IDLE it does not find the file anymore. When called from the shell it doesn't work either.
- Python obviousely does not find the path to the input.txt
- the issue is, to my understanding, not related to VBA. The error occures also when using shell commands

Solution was to put :

```
import os 
os.chdir(r"fullpath")
```

into my script this changes the current working directory to my path and then input.txt gets found.

Comment: "When I run this the output file doesn't get printed, which means the script doesn't run properly." Huh? You don't print anything in that script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the script from shell the working directory for the script will be the directory from which it is called upon.
Most IDLE define their own working directory.
To check I suggest doing:

```
os.getcwd()
```

in both cases and look what directory is used in both cases

Comment: both shell and IDLE print the same path.. But I think it has to be something like that. Why else should the shell not be able to find the input.txt file..

Comment: no wonder, the sys.argv[0] is always the path the script, see the edit for what you need